# Why am I still seeing old icon?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to update the `ic_launcher.png` file for my app.  For some reason I still get this very small old version of the icon in the "App setting" on my phone:

[image]

Also when I see the uninstall screen the icon is not right:

[image]

But after hit 'uninstall' the confirmation screen's icon is good.
[image]

Also the launcher icon looks fine on the Home screen when the app is installed.

[image]

Comment: Uninstall the APK from your phone and rebuild the project.

Comment: Can you show me where is you icon image in res folder?

Comment: Have you modify the images for all resolution? Problems like this might suggest that you only have correct images in certain resolution

Comment: Make sure you have proper icons for all resolution

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Restarting my phone seems to have corrected the problem.

Comment: Make sure your ic_launcher icon size matches android's launcher icon size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting my phone seems to have corrected the problem.

Comment: For me it didn't solve the problem. Android 11, API level 30.

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the images for all kind of resolutions. And place those images in appropriate folders

in Folder res -> mipmap folders

- mipmap-mdip - 48 X 48 ic_launcher.png
- mipmap-hdip - 72 X 72 ic_launcher.png
- mipmap-xhdip - 96 X 96 ic_launcher.png
- mipmap-xxhdip - 144 X 144 ic_launcher.png

And call this icon in Manifest file as

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Make sure that you have all these above resolution images in appropriate folders. If you still face the problem, try uninstalling the existing apk from device. Clean and rebuild the project and rerun it on your device.

Comment: I think all of these folders need to say *dpi instead of *dip

Answer (score 4):

Create **mipmap** folder in res directory right click on **res folder** => **copy path**  and goto that directory and create this folder  see in this image

[image: Create folder here]

After create this folder you can see this directory in android studio.

[image]

add this size of icon in your folder

```
LDPI - 36 x 36
MDPI - 48 x 48
HDPI - 72 x 72
XHDPI - 96 x 96
XXHDPI - 144 x 144
XXXHDPI - 192 x 192.
```

then add this icon in android manifest file

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo">

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Icon size will depend on your phone `DPI`s make sure you provide all supported sizes.